# MongoDB / Mongoose - When updating an array field with fewer elements problems

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that looks like:

```
    name: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 150,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 350
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'active'
    },
    targets: [ {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Thing',
        index: true
    } ]
```

});

The problem is with targets. Creating and adding to that array is no problem. However, if I reduce the number of elements in the array, it updates the targets, but does NOT reduce the size of the array, which causes numerous problems.

For example if targets = ["111111111111111111111111", "222222222222222222222222", "333333333333333333333333"]
and I do an update with targets = ["111111111111111111111111", "333333333333333333333333"],
the resulting array is ["111111111111111111111111", "333333333333333333333333", "333333333333333333333333"] since it doesn't reduce the size of the array.

I've looked at numerous things, and can't figure this out. The actual targets in my case can have several hundred elements. Also, doing an $addToSet doesn't seem to work, as it still won't remove the extra elements at the end. I really can't do a $slice, either - at least I haven't figured-out a way to do that. When I tried, I got an error saying that I couldn't update the same field twice.

How does one do this?

Here is the update code:

```
let filter = {
    _id: aRecord._id
};
let update = aRecord;
MyCollection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, (err, insertStatus) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return next(err);
    }
    if (1 === insertStatus.ok) {
        res.status(200);
    }
    return res.json(insertStatus);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your update code?

Comment: let filter      = { _id: aRecord._id };
let update  = aRecord;

MyCollection.findOneAndUpdate( filter, update,
            (err, insertStatus) => {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.error( err );
                    return next(err);
                }

                if (1 === insertStatus.ok)
                {
                    res.status(200);
                }
                return res.json(insertStatus);
            }
        );

Comment: Could you please edit the question, and update your code in there along with how you have `aRecord` constructed for update.

Answer (score 0):

Seems stupid, but this works when reducing number of array elements of an array field:

{ $push:{ targets: { $each: sourceArray, $position: 0, $slice: sourceArray.length } } };

Basically, insert the array of elements in the front, then truncate the array to the length of the source array.
This assumes the source array has entire list of array elements. So, the front-end, user changes the number of checkboxes in a list - it sends the entire list of checkboxes, not a delta.